# Modifying the current row based on the previous row in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a result set like this:

```
YearMonth  Sales
201411     100
201412     100
201501     100
201502     100
201503     100
201504     100
201505     100
201506     100
201507     100
201508     100
```

Need to add another row with 4% more sales than the previous month. For example my Result should be

```
YearMonth  Sales  New Sales
201411     100    100.00
201412     100    104.00
201501     100    108.16
201502     100    112.49
201503     100    116.99
201504     100    121.67
201505     100    126.53
201506     100    131.59
201507     100    136.86
201508     100    142.33
```

Please help me to get the best way for it.

Comment: What's the datatype of column YearMonth? Char or integer? Does the YearMonth always continuous? If not, how to calculate next sales after a gap?

Comment: Month 07/2015 has sales = 100, thus next month 08/2015 should have sales = 104, not 142.33.

Comment: Additional 4% on 100 will be 104 for all the values. You have not mentioned to calculate on new sales value.

Comment: create a new row or column? NewSales column already u have ?

Comment: YearMonth is Varchar. YearMonth is continuous always.

Comment: 4% should be on the previous row of the "New Sales". Only first row should be 100.

Comment: Need to display the new column "New Sales" in a report. Need not add it to the physical table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got perfect answer for your requirement. It took long time to figure out. Just change the #Temp table name with your table name and verify the column names also.

```
DECLARE @nCurrentSale FLOAT
DECLARE @nYeatDate INT
DECLARE @nSale FLOAT

CREATE TABLE #TempNEW(YearMonth VARCHAR(10), Sales FLOAT, NewSale FLOAT) 
SELECT TOP 1 @nCurrentSale =  Sales FROM #Temp 
   ORDER BY (CAST('01/' + SUBSTRING (CAST(YearMonth AS VARCHAR), 5 , 2) + '/' + SUBSTRING (CAST(YearMonth AS 
        VARCHAR), 0 , 5) AS DATETIME)) ASC

 DECLARE Cursor1 CURSOR FOR
        SELECT YearMonth, Sales FROM #Temp
        ORDER BY (CAST('01/' + SUBSTRING (CAST(YearMonth AS VARCHAR), 5 , 2) + '/' + SUBSTRING (CAST(YearMonth AS 
            VARCHAR), 0 , 5) AS DATETIME)) ASC

    OPEN Cursor1

    FETCH NEXT FROM Cursor1 INTO @nYeatDate, @nSale

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN  
        INSERT INTO #TempNEW(YearMonth, Sales, NewSale) VALUES(@nYeatDate, @nSale, CAST(@nCurrentSale AS DECIMAL(12,2)))

        SET @nCurrentSale = @nCurrentSale + ((@nCurrentSale/100) * 4)

        FETCH NEXT FROM Cursor1 INTO @nYeatDate, @nSale
    END

    CLOSE Cursor1
    DEALLOCATE Cursor1

SELECT * FROM #TempNEW
```

Notify me with your status.

Comment: Thank you very much Veera..Actually, My initial data set is not a table but is fetched from a query along with many other fields. I am working on it now. Thanks again!!

Comment: Is there any other way we can do in Server 2012, as my dataset contains 10 million rows and it may be slow to use a cursor.

Comment: i TRY TO FIGURE THAT OUT

Answer (score 0):

Yes it possible. But first you have to alter the table and add the extra column NewSales then try with this link 
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34243/update-row-based-on-match-to-previous-row
 i think you can done it through this link
Also sql server support some "Computed Columns in SQL Server with Persisted Values"
using that you can specify the formula what you want, then the new column value  will automatically created according to your formula

Answer (score 0):

Here's two thoughts... Not super clear if I understood the use case... Also this solution will only work for SQL 2012 and up

So given the table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LagExample](
    [YearMonth] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Sales] [money] NOT NULL
)
```

First one is fairly simple and just assumes you are wanting to base the magnitude of your percentage increase on how many days came before it...

```
;WITH cte
as
(
    SELECT YearMonth,
       ROW_NUMBER()  OVER (ORDER BY YearMonth) - 1 AS SalesEntry,
        cast(LAG(Sales, 1,Sales) OVER (ORDER BY YearMonth) as float) as Sales
    FROM LagExample
)
SELECT YearMonth, 
        Sales,
       cast(Sales * POWER(cast(1.04 as float), SalesEntry) AS decimal(10,2)) as NewSales
FROM cte
```

The Second one uses a recursive CTE to calculate the value as you move along the months..
Here's a good link about recursive CTEs
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/683011/How-to-use-recursive-CTE-calls-in-T-SQL

```
;with data
as
(
    SELECT Lead(le.YearMonth, 1, null) OVER (ORDER BY le.YearMonth) as NextYearMonth, 
            cast(le.Sales as Decimal(10,4)) as Sales,
            le.YearMonth
    FROM LagExample le
)
,cte
as
(
    SELECT *
    FROM data
    Where YearMonth = '201411'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
       data.NextYearMonth, 
       cast(cte.Sales * 1.04 as Decimal(10,4)) as Sales,
       data.YearMonth
    From cte join 
        data on data.YearMonth = cte.NextYearMonth
)
SELECT YearMonth, cast(Sales as Decimal(10,2))
FROM cte
order by YearMonth
```